# swift will I be forced to remake my app's code when swift 2.0 is released

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have made an app using swift 1.2.

Will I be forced to rebuild my entire using swift 2 when its released?
Or can I still make updates to my app using swift 1.2 code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's my understanding that Xcode 7 uses Swift 2, and Xcode 6.x uses Swift 1.2.

Apple will probably continue to support Xcode 6.x for some time after Xcode 7 goes GM. During that time you should be able to support your Swift 1.2 code. However, it's not a good idea to depend on old developer tools. You should think about migrating to Swift 2 once Xcode 7 is released.

Answer (score 0):

When i used xcode 7.beta 4, i converted my code for swift 2. when i ran the same code with xcode 7.beta 5, again i ran into few more swift related errors. better keep calm until Apple releases the final xcode version which supports swift 2+